# How to get the next value of sequence?

Tags: db2, sequence

Could somebody tell what is wrong with obvious query below:

```
db2 => select next value for schema_name.sequence_name;
```

As a result I'm getting:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following
"schema_name.sequence_name".  Expected tokens may include:  "<table_expr>".
SQLSTATE=42601
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to select from something. Another option is:

```
db2 => values next value for schema_name.sequence_name;
```

As you noted you can also use `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` or create a virtual table:

```
db2 => select next value for schema_name.sequence_name from ( values 1 );
```

Answer (score 6):

`db2 => select next value for schema_name.sequence_name from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;`

did the trick

Answer (score -2):

In this query:

```
select next value for schema_name.sequence_name;
```

`next value` is creating problem because we can not make the spaces while writing a query. So other thing you can do is found the max of value and increase it by 1.

Below find query for that:

```
select max(value)+1 for schema_name.sequence_name;
```

This would be helpful for you.

Comment: you can't select from nothing in db2. You need to use either `values next value for schema_name.sequence_name` or `select next value for schema_name.sequence_name from ...`. In addition you cant apply max to value the way you do, `next value for schema_name.sequence_name` is an expression that returns the next value from the sequence.